# Meaning of "not that"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in some novel. It goes like

"There was an artists' lounge backstage. Not that anybody called it it that - only Roxana"

What does it mean here?

Comment: It'd be nice to know what novel it's from. Anyway, I think it's "Not that anybody called it that". Only one *that*. Also, see: [not that](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/not#not__17) "used for adding a negative statement that reduces the effect or the importance of what you have just said".

Comment: From Elif Shafak's novel. @damekerng T.

Answer (score 2):

"Not that" negates a sentence and shows a contrast with the *implications* of the previous sentence. It's like a combination of "but" and "not". After the first sentence, the reader would expect all of the characters to call the room an artists' lounge. But the second sentence says no -- only Roxana does that.

Here's another version of your example:

> The room backstage was an artists' lounge, but nobody called it that except Roxana.